# Автоматическое приведение типов

Tags: java

Выдержка из пособия по Java:

> В Java, в отличие от некоторых других языков, отсутствует
>   автоматическое приведение типов. Несовпадение типов приводит не к
>   предупреждению при трансляции, а к сообщению об ошибке. Для каждого
>   типа строго определены наборы допустимых значений и разрешенных
>   операций.

Однако практический пример работает (производится вычисление между операндами разного типа):

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int y = 54;
        double x = 1.543E4;
        char f = '2';
        double h = y*x*f;
        System.out.println(h);
    }
}
```

В пособии имеется ввиду что-то другое? Приведите, пожалуйста, пример несовпадения типов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего имеется ввиду ситуация с выполнением присваивания;

Данный фрагмент кода скомпилируется в C, но приведёт к ошибке компиляции в Java:

```
double a = 3.2;
int b = a;
```

**UPD:**

В Java есть приведение примитивов по следующей цепочке:

```
byte –> short -> int –> long –> float –> double
```

т.е. когда у вас есть `int a = 1; long b = 2;` то результат арифметической операции `a*b` будет `long`.

Это связано с определением чисел, например в `byte` всего 1 байт которое может содержать число от -127 до 128, в int попадает весь диапазон чисел `byte`, потому что там 4 байта, `float` и `double` могут содержать числа в экспоненциальной форме, так что они могут представлять `long` и т. п.

Comment: Понял, то есть неявное приведение типов работает только в сторону увеличения типов по объему памяти, но не наоборот. byte -> short -> int -> long

Comment: да, как раз дописывал

Comment: char просто скастовался к byte при выполнении арифметической операции

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую - Шилдт Г. - Java 8. Полное руководство - 2015. Там очень хорошо все об этом описано. По поводу вашего примера добавьте - 
String str="string";
h = y*x*f+str;
и увидите что получится.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и ссылку на книгу. Но String - это объект. А вот Char - примитив. И если содержит значение '1', то участвует в арифметических выражениях.